# How to sample from skewed data to get a mixed distribution output in r?

Tags: r, sampling, normal-distribution

I have a dataset of gene lengths that looks a bit like this:

```
Gene  Length
Gene1  5
Gene2  6
Gene3  400000
Gene4  1000
Gene5  25000
Gene6  10
Gene7  50
Gene8  4
Gene9  100
Gene10 2000
```

The distribution of the `Length` is skewed with most genes having a very small size. I'm looking to see if I can make a sample generator that selects a subset of genes that would have differing sizes not just genes that are very small in this range of length data - giving me a list of genes with a mix of lengths in a unbiased/as random a way as possible.

I'm not sure where to start with this. I've been looking into using the `sample()` function but I haven't been able to get it to sample and consider that I want a subset of genes with mix of gene lengths, not just those in the very small sizes in the range of lengths I have - is what I'm trying to do possible?

Example input data:

```
df <- structure(list(Gene = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4", "Gene5", 
"Gene6", "Gene7", "Gene8", "Gene9", "Gene10"), Length = c(5L, 
6L, 400000L, 1000L, 25000L, 10L, 50L, 4L, 100L, 2000L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Edit:

I am now running this code to sample:

```
genes_selected <- sample(nrow(df), size = 51, replace=FALSE, 
                            prob=dnorm(df$Gene_length,
                                       mean(df$Gene_length),
                                       sd(df$Gene_length)))
```

But what I would like is to random select genes that are in the the upper tail of the `dnorm()`/normal distribution - is this possible to add into `prob` of `sample()`?

Comment: I think you need to undertake a transformation of your data.  try something like df$Length <- log(df$Length)  then plot your data again.

Comment: Why do you want a normal distribution? Gene lengths are not likely to follow a normal distribution because no gene can have a negative length. A log-normal distribution is plausible or Poisson, but not normal.

Comment: Normal distribution is probably the wrong term (I have no stats training so I'm a bit blind with what I'm doing). I'm looking to get a subset of genes with mixed lengths ultimately, so not every single gene in the group is in the hundreds in size only. I'll re-word my question. The transformation point is really helpful and looks like it might be what I need - thank you for this!

Comment: There's probably a way to do this precisely by setting the weights appropriately for `sample()`.  It's possible that something like `sample(nrow(df), size=..., replace=FALSE, weights=dnorm(df$Length, mean(df$Length), sd(df$Length))` would go in the right direction

Comment: Thank you for this, how do I get ```weights``` to be considered in ```sample()```? Right now when I try to comes back that: ```Error in sample(nrow(df), replace = FALSE, weights = dnorm(df$Length,  : 
  unused argument (weights = dnorm(df$Length, mean(df$Length), sd(df$Length)))```

Comment: I've had a go at doing this now with using ```prob()``` but I'd like to set the prob to consider random sampling from the upper part of the normal distribution, if that makes sense, if this possible? I've updated my question with what I've done exactly

Comment: I think you need to simply sample *with* replacement: `genes_selected <- sample(nrow(df), size = 51, replace = TRUE)`. This will preserve the underlying distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this example can help.

Let's assume the Genes follow a Weibull distribution :

```
classes <- df[order(df$Length)]
classes$density <- dweibull(1:nrow(df), shape=1, scale=1)
classes

     Gene Length      density
 1:  Gene8      4 3.678794e-01
 2:  Gene1      5 1.353353e-01
 3:  Gene2      6 4.978707e-02
 4:  Gene6     10 1.831564e-02
 5:  Gene7     50 6.737947e-03
 6:  Gene9    100 2.478752e-03
 7:  Gene4   1000 9.118820e-04
 8: Gene10   2000 3.354626e-04
 9:  Gene5  25000 1.234098e-04
10:  Gene3 400000 4.539993e-05
```

[image]
Now let's replicate the classes according to their density:

```
dfrep <- classes[rep(1:nrow(classes), classes$density*100000)]
```

We now have a 'skewed' distribution with short Genes (Gene 8, Gene 1, ...) over represented :

```
table(dfrep$Gene)

 Gene1 Gene10  Gene2  Gene3  Gene4  Gene5  Gene6  Gene7  Gene8  Gene9 
 13533     33   4978      4     91     12   1831    673  36787    247
```

We can get the classes distribution and calculate a density

```
classes <- table(dfrep$Gene)
density_calc <- classes/sum(classes)
dfrep$density_calc <- density_calc[match(dfrep$Gene,names(density_calc))]
```

If we want to `sample` equal number of Genes from each class, we can use the `prob` argument to sample according to inverse of `density_calc` :

```
table(sample(dfrep$Gene, size=1000, prob=1/dfrep$density_calc, replace=T))

 Gene1 Gene10  Gene2  Gene3  Gene4  Gene5  Gene6  Gene7  Gene8  Gene9 
   101     90    111     96     92     99    102    110    101     98
```

Which allows to get similar amount of each Gene from the skewed distribution.

Comment: @DN1, does my edit with reverse calculation of density answer your question?

Comment: Thank you for this, is there a way for me to identify the range of samples that fall into the right tail of the plot?

Comment: @DN1, not sure I fully get your last question: do you mean identify the index of the rows?

Comment: If you have a chance to look at this again, for my own understanding why do you multiple by 100000 in the line ```dfrep <- classes[rep(1:nrow(classes), classes$density*100000)]``` - do you choose the 100000 number based on looking at the class$density?

Comment: @DN1, exactly, this was to make sure that `rep` would get a number greater than 1, as `classes$density` is in `10^-5` range for the least represented Gene in Weibull law taken as example.